# Jumpy/Glitchy Motion Tracking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, tracking, motion-capture

I am in the process of finishing my first own blender project (woo!) and have encountered some interesting behavior.

The camera seems to be jumping/skipping whilst tracking, causing my text rendering to do the same.

Here are a couple gifs to illustrate my points.

[image]

[GIF #2](http://gph.is/1SJIFJl) ( >2 MiB)

When I solved for camera motion I got an error 1.5. Is this a result of that? If so how can I get a smaller error? More trackers? The footage isn't the best to begin with but I want to salvage what I can.

I've consulted [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/how-to-pick-good-keyframes-for-motion-tracking?lq=1) on picking good keyframes as well as [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19638/motion-tracking-round-objects) for tracking round objects but i'm not certain that that is the problem, and for the round tracking the camera solver caused the text to move instead of staying spatially locked.

Otherwise it seems to get all the factors correct, namely scale and rotation, but has a minor couple hiccups. Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/camera-tracking-problem

Comment: 1.5 as error is still too high. Refine your tracking to get under .3

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8934/some-data-failed-to-reconstruct-motion-tracking/8969#8969

Comment: To fix the orientation of your image see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/camera-alignment-to-origin-issues/28888#28888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you cegaton, the articles you posted in the comments helped me fix the process. I erased all the trackers that gave higher than a .5 solve error and additionally tracked parts of the scenes on different axes and on both sides of the 3D text I am tracking, manually adjusting the tracks/empties where necessary using the graphs also found in your comments to find troublesome empties.

As well, I chose previous frame from within the tracking windows, and tracked motion with **Affine** instead of the default Loc/LocRot. I did this until I achieved a solve error of 0.3.

Big shoutout to cegaton, thank you!