# Map motions from real into 3D

Tags: motion-capture

I had a great idea and wondered if there is a simple way to record the motions of, for example, my face and then map them onto a model in Blender?
This would be really cool, if there was a free program for that or something similar...

Comment: Without any mocap studio (or mocap hardware at least) it's hard work. Otherwise you can stay in blender and reconstruct the motion of the head by using blenders object tracker, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19638/motion-tracking-round-objects In order to deform the head geometry basic rigging skills and extra markers are required to drive some bones by the markers, see *Sebastion König's Face Deformation Test*: https://vimeo.com/34610690

Answer (score 0):

Such a technique exists, it is widely used and there are free programs capable of doing it. It is called *facial motion capture* (or facial mocap for short) and  vanilla Blender has tools for it.

A quick Google search found this: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?243419-Facial-Mocap-Tutorial-(Basic)

Looking up "blender facial motion capture tutorial" on your favourite search engine should find you tutorials on how to do it.

Comment: Is there free software, that does the capturing on its own?

Comment: What do you mean by "on its own"?

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't know anything outside Blender in general. I am not the right person to ask.

Comment: Oh okay. I meant that i only would have to put in the data and it does all the tracking etc for me...

Comment: When using Blender you have to have markers (physical dots) on the face. Then you tell Blender where they are. Then you can eg. export the motions into empty objects. They could then be used as drivers for shapekeys or bones.

Comment: I don't think it can be done in a much simpler way, but I could be very much wrong.

Comment: Yes I know how that works, but I am looking for something more automated...

Comment: This could be a step in the right direction: https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/re-face-facial-motion-capture-retargeting-tools-v1-0/ (Though it costs money)

Comment: Like I said, I am looking for some software that creates the motion capture data on its own... But i think there is not any free software...

Comment: I mean anything you do kinda dependes on the rig you have.

Comment: Currently i am more interested in facial captures.. But I am looking for a solution that might work for the whole body too... 

Answer (score 0):

you can check out OpenKinect I don't know if it does what you are looking for ti will capture body movements but I don't know about the face capture... but there are pay alternatives like http://www.faceshift.com/ that does it... or you can check out something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_AwDv9Al28 with putting dots on your face like they did in movie Dawn of the Planet of the Apes ... just an FYI if you didn't know the Kinect method doesn't work well in sunlight that's why they had to use the dots but with the dots you should use it at high fps capture rate like 60+ the higher the batter and try not to drop the resolution to much... FYI a lot of action camera's like the gopro's have high fps... I don't know if that will help you.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with blender. However, as the question has nothing to do with blender either, I'll say this is a good answer on a bad question.