# How does one align an object to trackers in 3d view?

Tags: animation, camera, tracking

There must be a way to align an object to trackers, but I don’t know how or where to find this feature. Basically, I want to snap an object to a single, or collection of trackers in the 3d view after a solve. Specifically, an object solve, but at this point, it doesn’t matter. I get the feeling that it’s even possible to align and orient a 3d object to a group of trackers. I’m at a loss.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19638/motion-tracking-round-objects/19712#19712

Answer (score 1):

In the Solve section you have two options:

3D trackers to mesh (which will create vertex where the selected trackers are)

or

Link Empty to track (which will create an empty in the 3D environment to which you can parent objects)