# motion tracking : how to extract 3d position from selected 2d tracker

Tags: tracking

I already solve my camera and created 3d scene successfully. Now i want to do 2d track the original clip and by using solving data, i want to extract that specific point into 3d coordinate (as empty object or plain axes). How can i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [how does one align an object to trackers in 3D view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102391/how-does-one-align-an-object-to-trackers-in-3d-view/102392#102392)

Comment: Relateed: [How would I attach tex to a tracked point on video clip?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Link Empty to track**, which will create an empty in the 3D environment that correspond to the tracker

[image]